# C Sprintf Format Error

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I'm trying to format the given string and printf it. Bu it doesnt work. It gives error Any idea?

```
  char* query_buffer;

  sprintf(query_buffer,"%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x;%u.%u.%u.%u;%d\n",
      node_config->mac_address.addr[0], node_config->mac_address.addr[1], node_config->mac_address.addr[2], node_config->mac_address.addr[3],
      node_config->mac_address.addr[4], node_config->mac_address.addr[5], node_config->mac_address.addr[6], node_config->mac_address.addr[7],
      ip64_addr->u8[0], ip64_addr->u8[1], ip64_addr->u8[2], ip64_addr->u8[3],
      node_config->coap_port);

  printf("%s\n",query_buffer);
```

If I try below printf it works. I couldnt understand what is different between doing these two.

```
  printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x;%u.%u.%u.%u;%d\n",
  node_config->mac_address.addr[0], node_config->mac_address.addr[1], node_config->mac_address.addr[2], node_config->mac_address.addr[3],
  node_config->mac_address.addr[4], node_config->mac_address.addr[5], node_config->mac_address.addr[6], node_config->mac_address.addr[7],
  ip64_addr->u8[0], ip64_addr->u8[1], ip64_addr->u8[2], ip64_addr->u8[3],
  node_config->coap_port);
```

Comment: The last `%u;%d` looks suspicious. Did you mean `%u:%d`? You will need to post your *data* and a MCVE for anyone to give a definite answer. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `char* query_buffer;` declares a pointer to a char but it the memory it points to might not be declared. So you can get a segmentation fault when you call `sprintf` to access that memory. Try declaring `query_buffer` like `char *query_buffer = (char*)malloc(256);`. That will create a pointer *and* declare 256 bytes at where it points to.

Comment: `char query_buffer[256]` is an array declaration, not a pointer.